# Publish crystal reports with htm-based parameter page to the intranet

Tags: crystal-reports, parameters, crystal-reports-server

Is there a way to publish my crystal reports and call them throuh html-based parameter page (preferably jsp) to our intranet?

We have developed reports using Crystal Reports, and we want users to be able to call these reports through an HTML-based page through our itnranet.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see you used the "Crystal Reports Server" tag -- that answers your question right there. :-) It provides web viewing, report scheduling, and all sorts of nifty backend features.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider a solution like rePORTAL at http://www.reportalsoftware.com. It allows you to securely publish reports for web access via your intranet or extranet. No need for coding.